# What is "friend" keyword used for?

Tags: c++, definition

Can you explain to me why the `friend` keyword is preferred for giving access rights to private data of class?

Comment: If you ask for why `friend` was preferred, what other ways do you usually use to access private class data from the outside?

Comment: @honk "Preferred" might be the wrong word to use here. I edited most of the post to correct grammar and whatnot and I kept the original word choice, but I think there may be a language barrier here.

Comment: I don't know because I read about friend today by chance. and the article says if I don't use friend, I will create a monolit class.

Answer (score 18):

Friend is the classic way of extending the interface of a class.
But the great thing is that friend explicitly documents your intention to tightly bind specific items to a class.

Note: By using friend you are tightly binding the friends to the class.

A perfect example is the stream operators in C++

```
class Plop
{
    private:
        int  value;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Plop const& data);
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Plop&       data);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Plop const& data)
{
     return stream << data.value << " ";
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Plop&       data)
{
     return stream >> data.value;
}
```

Here we are extending the public interface of the Plop class in a way that allows us to stream the object into and out of a stream, but without exposing the internal implementation or causing future implementation headaches by requiring the use of get/set methods that must be maintained (because they would be part of the public interface) even if the internal implementation is changed.

Note: This does **NOT** break encapsulation but it does tightly bind the stream operators to the implementation of the Plop class (ie any change to the implementation of the Plop class will require a change to the implementation of the stream operators). But this is expected. All parts of the public interface (including public/protected methods) are tightly bound to the implementation.

But Note: You have explicitly documented this binding as part of the class declaration.

Note: I would not refer to friend as the preferred way to expose private data. Over-use of friend can be just as bad as exposing the implementation. Like all language features it should be used judiciously.

Comment: If you could publicly access the data (e.g. via a getter) would you have used a free function instead?